# Use https for specific application under IIS 6 website

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, ssl, iis

We have an intranet server that hosts many web applications / web services in various virtual directories all located under the default web site in IIS6.  These all just use http connections on port 80 e.g. "http://ourintranetsite/applicationname" or "http://ourintranetsite/servicename" etc.

We have a new web service that we have deployed to a virtual directory under the default web site and it works fine using an http connection.  One issue has arisen now that we are starting to use SharePoint Online.  We want to be able to call this web service from some client site script on a SP Online page, but it is causing an issue because the SP Online page is using https, so it doesn't like calling a web service over http (IE just puts a warning message in the browser console, but Chrome refuses to make the call at all).

Is it possible to configure just the virtual directory hosting this web service to require an SSL connection rather than setting it at the web site level?  We really don't want everything under the default web site to start requiring https, just this particular service.  Obviously I could just tick the "Require secure channel (SSL)" option in the properties of the virtual directory, but from what I understand (I've not had to use SSL before), the default port for that will be 443 while the website is using port 80.  Ideally we'd just like to be able to get to the service with something like "https://ourintranetsite/secureservice/..." while not impacting any of the existing http applications and services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible to assign a certificate to virtual directory, however when you add a cert to the website all it does makes the site brow sable over https but that doesn't mean that it has to be browsed only over https.

What I meant is you can have site to be brow sable over http and https. Add the necessary cert to the site and make sure you do not check "Require secure channel (SSL)" and it should be good to go.